# How to Access data elements

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access data elements, but seems like it doesnt work.

Here is the code from inspector:

```
$('#question-answer-container,#new_question')
[<form novalidate=​"novalidate" class=​"simple_form new_question" id=​"new_question" action=​"/​questions" accept-charset=​"UTF-8" method=​"post">​…​</form>​, <div id=​"question-answer-container">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"well" data-uri=​"localhost:​3000/​question/​1" id=​"new_question">​</div>​]

$('#question-answer-container,#new_question').data('uri')
undefined
```

How do I get hold of 'data-uri' above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.data()` or `.attr("data-*")`.

While calling it, use this:

```
$('#question-answer-container[data-uri], #new_question[data-uri]');
```

The code you have added, with `.data("uri")` fetches the attribute's value.

The code which I have added with the data URI in the selector, selects the element, which is what you need at the moment.

Comment: Because your answer is wrong. OP wants the value of the attribute.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to access the attribute by adding a bit on @PraveenKumar's answer. Once you add this to your answer I will accept it as correct $('#question-answer-container[data-uri], #new_question[data-uri]').data('uri')

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your answer, it's a bit unclear what you meant. I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @codeObserver the underlying problem is that both the `<form>` and the `<div>` have `id="new_question"`, an ID should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing duplicate `id` `new_question` from `div` , utilizing selector `$(".well")`

```js
var data = $(".well").data("uri");
console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_question" id="new_question" action="/questions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">...</form>
<div id="question-answer-container">...</div>,
<div class="well" data-uri="localhost:3000/question/1">...</div>
```

Comment: Hm, right here in the page. I'm running it in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Wait, I was wrong. I forgot console.log doesn't output in the page itself.